# Howto pipe: cp | tar | gzip without creating intermediary files?

Tags: gzip, pipe, tar

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to pipe | this without having to create a physical file anywhere between A and B.tar.gz?

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. File A
2. Rename A to B
3. Tar B.tar
4. gzip -9 B.tar.gz

So for example:

```
cp A B | tar cvf - B | gzip -9 B.tar.gz
```

Comment: why would you like to pipe `cp A B` ?

Comment: rename is `mv`.

Comment: Please explain why you would like to copy `A` to `B` first.

Answer (score 55):

The following examples can be used to avoid creating intermediary files:

tar with gzip:

`tar cf - A | gzip -9 > B.tar.gz`

gzip without tar:

`gzip -9c A > B.gz`

tar without gzip:

`tar cf B.tar A`

Renaming (moving) `A` to `B` first doesn't make sense to me. If this is intended, then just put a `mv A B &&` before either of the above commands and exchange `A` with `B` there.

Example with tar and gzip:

`mv A B && tar cf - B | gzip -9 > B.tar.gz`

Comment: This is correct and should be marked as such. You must include a "-" after "tar" for the piped option otherwise you get "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive".

Comment: This does not answer the question because the filename stored in the tar file is A, not B. The problem has not been solved.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on your version of tar

If you have the version that supports member transforms (--transform or --xform) then you can simply do

```
tar -c --transform=s/A/B/ A | gzip -9 > B.tar.gz
```

the | gzip -9 >B.tar.gz can be avoided if your tar supports the -z option

```
tar -zcvf B.tar.gz --transform=s/A/B/ A
```

If your version of tar doesn't support --transform then you will have to just copy the file first eg

```
 cp A B && tar -zcvf B.tar.gz B
```

However if you are only compressing one file why not skip the tar part all together and just do

```
cat A | gzip -9 > B.gz
```

Comment: I've used cp as you did in your example but rename is mv

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cp` to make a copy with a different name/location, then just include the full/final pathname you want when creating your completed .gzip file:

```
tar -cvf existing.file | gzip -1 > ./newdirectory/newnamed.file.tgz
```

Comment: This does not work, produces "tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive".

Comment: @Adambean Maybe you want to use `tar -czf - some-folder > some-archive.tar.gz`?

Comment: @tsauerwein, yes, see my reply to the below answer from 14 months ago...